# Raise validation when recive extra key in yup object

Tags: javascript, yup

I am using `yup` for object validations. I have the following schema

```js
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required(),
});
```

I am validating it with object

```js
{
  "name": "Foo",
  "desc": "Lorem ipsum"
}
```

Yup validates this object although it has an extra key `desc`. I want to raise the error for extra keys in the object.

I have tried with `abortEarly` and `stripUnknown` in `.validate` but it doesn't work.

```js
schema.validateSync(data, { strict: true, stripUnknown: true })
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to append the .strict() to the object you are validating. This makes the validation fail and then you can handle the error however you wish to do that.

So, in your case, change your schema to this:

```
  const schema = yup.object().shape({
    name: yup.string().required()
}).noUnknown(true).strict();


await schema.validate(data, { abortEarly: false });
```

Comment: You say `strict` is the important part, but `noUnknown(true)` seems like it does the job. Are both required in combination to accomplish this? Since you do both in your answer, you should explain what purpose each serves. (And you should verify that both _are_ needed.)

Answer (score 0):

Complementing our friend response:

**noUnknown** - Validate that the object value only contains keys specified in shape().

**strict** - Only validate the input, skipping type casting and transformation

**stripUnknown** - Remove unspecified keys from objects. When **'strict'** is set to true, **'stripUnknown'** will automatically be set to false.

So, to do it right you should add these 3 options to your validation:

```
{ abortEarly: false, strict: false, stripUnknown: false }
```

And therefore:

```
.noUnknown(true)
```

**Example: Block extra keys (to exit with error) and transform Date.**

```
export const updateCustomerValidation = validation((getSchema) => ({
    params: getSchema<IParamsUpdateClientes>(yup.object().shape({
        clid: yup.string().required()
    })),
    body: getSchema<IBodyUpdateClientes>(yup.object().shape({
        ...
        data_nascimento: yup.date().transform((value) => new Date(value))
    }).noUnknown(true)
    )
}));
```

**Tip**: Yup validate a date using Date() constructor, so you have to transform it before validating.

Yup has such a bad documentation, I hope they update it soon.